# What happened to Shirley's children in Dear Zachary?

Tags: character, dear-zachary

I loved the film [Dear Zachary: A Letter to a Son About His Father](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjAvviAyIvLAhVLfxoKHSb2DlYQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDear_Zachary%3A_A_Letter_to_a_Son_About_His_Father&usg=AFQjCNEZPkITlqnyn9dnxK1Z4DEQPO0RxA&bvm=bv.114733917,d.d2s), but in the end, I wondered what happened to Shirley's kids later on as I felt bad for them as they would be traumatised for having such an evil mother.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a definitive, well-known answer to this. The film-maker was asked it [in a Q and A](http://kurtkuenne.newsvine.com/_news/2008/12/02/2170527-ask-the-filmmaker-a-question-about-dear-zachary) and stated:

> **Gretchen P** asks:
>
> Do you have children of your own and what about Shirley's other
>   children?
>
> **Kurt Kuenne**:
>
> Thanks so much for writing, Gretchen. I do not have children of my own
>   at this time in my life, which is perhaps why I was able to
>   emotionally get through the making and editing of this movie in its
>   final form. (Though I do recall that while editing, I would take a
>   lunch break and go over to a friend's house, see his 3 year old son
>   and just about come apart...if that makes any sense.)
>
> Shirley's other children were left with a horrible burden, and while I
>   haven't kept close contact with them - the only one I have had contact
>   with in the last 5 years is her son TJ, who you saw toward the end of
>   the film. But I wish them absolutely all the best in dealing with a
>   burden that no child should ever have to carry. They are innocent
>   victims in this too. And I do hope that, if this movie helps cause
>   some kind of change to the system, that it will honor the memory of
>   their little brother.

As the *other* children were in their 20s and there was no issue of either parental custody or any fault on their part, they don't appear to have been focussed on in any of the subsequent investigations or reports into their mother's behaviour (and understandably so).

Therefore, I think this is the most information we'll get on the matter.